# What to do about a not-fully-answered question that is too old to be migrated to an appropriate site

Tags: support, specific-question, migration, cross-posting

I had asked this question

- [What is the "Principle of permanence"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/751624/103816)

7 months ago and it was never fully answered (in particular the "how and why [the principle of permanence] has two different definitions" part wasn't answered).

There is a new SE site, [History of Science and Math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), where I might be more likely to get a full answer. I flagged my question for migration but was told that since my question is more than 60 days old, it can't be migrated. The only way left is to cross-post the question.

Please advise me about what I should do now.

Comment: If you're going to post it at another site, you  might have a look on some older discussion tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]). For example, [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) mentions some useful points. (And in some other discussions it is mentioned that you should wait some time after posting question at one site before posting it to another one, but in this particular case there was definitely long enough time).

Comment: [Here's the HSM question](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/606/why-does-principle-of-permanence-have-two-different-definitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the perspective of an active HSM user:**

Some parts of the question would be perfect for HSM:

> I also want to study the historical perspective of this term and want to know how and why it has two different definitions.

That's great for HSM. Another part is sort of on-the-fence:

> I want some references related to this term.

This could be on topic if and only if (yep, that's a joke!) you want some information about historical figures writing about their work regarding the topic. But this is quite the stretch.

I think that other parts of it, though, would be off-topic, because they do not relate to anything historical.

As a side note, Maura ALLEGRANZA's answer is one similar to what you will get on HSM - in fact, s/he has been very active there, writing more good answers.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to re-ask it at HSM, mentioning that

1. you asked at Math.SE long time ago (give a link)
2. the answers received  did not really answer the question (explain why)

You may also want to edit a link to HSM question into Math.SE question.

Answer (score 5):

Only an employee would be able migrate the question, and it is highly doubtful that they would do so in this instance. (In addition to being old, it's not actually off-topic here, and one of the criteria for migration is generally that it is *off-topic* on the original site.)

What I would recommend doing is first determine which parts of your question have not been satisfactorily answered here. Next, ask a **new and focused** question on hsm.SE that is suitable for *that site*. In particular, I am personally doubtful that the sub-question

> Could you guys explain me what the "Principle of permanence" actually is?

would be on-topic on hsm.SE (but, admittedly, I could be wrong).

Be sure to point out the provenance of the question (was originally asked on math.SE, wasn't answered satisfactorily because..., etc.), and, as another answer says, adding links from each question to the other is a good step to minimize the possibility of duplicated effort.

Comment: Ok, I will ask only that part which has not been answered yet.

Comment: *"The moderator is never wrong, he's merely testing your alertness and attention to details."* (The Handbook of Moderating)